# Python : _on_keyboard_down function pass value weird character like ā,Ă,ą

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

i am using `def _on_keyboard_down` in `python-2.7` and `kivy`. When i press 1,2,3 in keyboard then print `text` weird character like ā,Ă,ą. Can someone help me ?

```
 def _on_keyboard_down(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        print(text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
_on_keyboard_down(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
```

with

```
_on_keyboard_down(self, window, keycode, scancode, text, modifiers):
```

## Output

```
The keycode 49 have been pressed
 - text is '1'
 - modifiers are []
 - window= <kivy.core.window.window_sdl2.WindowSDL object at 0x7f91dc381180>
 - scancode= 30

The keycode 257 have been pressed
 - text is 'ā'
 - modifiers are []
 - window= <kivy.core.window.window_sdl2.WindowSDL object at 0x7f91dc381180>
 - scancode= 89

The key 258 have been pressed
 - text is 'Ă'
 - modifiers are []
 - window= <kivy.core.window.window_sdl2.WindowSDL object at 0x7f91dc381180>
 - scancode= 90
```

The keycode 259 have been pressed
     - text is 'ă'
     - modifiers are []
     - window= 
     - scancode= 91

## Numbers Keyboard

When the keyboard for digit 1 is pressed, the keycode is 49.

## NumPad Keyboard

When the NumPad keyboard is pressed, keycode=257 is for digit 1, keycode=258 is for digit 2, keycode=259 is for digit 3, etc.

Comment: thanks for reply. Can i get 1,2,3 text instead of weird characters when 89,90,91 key pressed?